# ¿Como puedo declarar en hacer un SELECT* FROM con varias columnas y mostrarlo en una tabla

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo un buscador en PHP con MySQL y al agregar numero de cuenta quiero que me desplegué ciertos campos de mi BD:
Este es mi código:

```
if(isset($_GET['enviar'])){
        $busqueda = $_GET['busqueda'];
       $consulta = $con -> query("SELECT * FROM alumno WHERE nocuenta LIKE '%$busqueda%'");
        while($row = $consulta->fetch_array()){
            echo $row['nocuenta'].'<br>';

        }

    }
```

Quiero agregar varias columnas y de otras tablas... Ayuda!!